# Cut number of character in the beginning of string and end of the string

Tags: ksh

I need to cut a number of characters from the beginning and end of a string. The string is does not have a specific format and can be random numbers and words. I am trying to remove 5 characters in the beginning and 11 from the end of the string.

Input string:

```
342136001788006DEEFF0000060000806000006HSV40002HP
```

Output string:

```
6001788006DEEFF000006000080600000
```

The bolded characters `3413` and `6HSV40002HP` are removed from the input.

Comment: What have you actually tried that didn't work? This is not a free coding site, but we will help you if you actually try and get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok found my answer using cut command which I was so focusing with awk & sed , but cut helps in the end

cut -c6-38 test.txt

Answer (score 0):

You found the `cut` commamd wat is the best solution in this case.
You wondered how you should do this with `sed`, which will be interesting for more complex situations.
The noob solution is (using `;` for 2 different substititions and `$` for end-of-line):

```
echo '342136001788006DEEFF0000060000806000006HSV40002HP' |
sed 's/.....//;s/...........$//'
```

You do not want to count the dots, you can tell how often a pattern repeats with `pattern{count}`.
And you can remember/recall a pattern with `s/..(pattern)../\1/'.

```
echo '342136001788006DEEFF0000060000806000006HSV40002HP' |
sed 's/.\{5\}\(.*\).\{11\}/\1/'
```

When your `sed` supports the flog `-r`, you can avoid all thise backslashes:

```
echo '342136001788006DEEFF0000060000806000006HSV40002HP' |
sed -r 's/.{5}(.*).{11}/\1/'
```